# Android broadcast receiver not getting called immediately after install

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an Android app that listens to SMS messages. This is in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingSMSBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The broadcast receivers works fine if the app is installed and opened. But I want the receiver to be able to be called immediately after install, in case user has remotely installed from the Android Market website and is not present in front of the phone. When I install APK using adb

```
 ./adb install myapp.apk
```

I can see the app is installed. But when I send a SMS message, my app doesnt respond. After I open the app once, it appears all the initialization happens at this point, and now the app responds to SMS messages just fine.

One possibility is that the ADB install is different from the Market install.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not Possible. AFAIK until receiver is not registered then it can not detect any action.You have not any problem with code.But your receiver will work when it start one.For this we have to run our application at least one time.So that Manifest Register the Receiver

Comment: How are they doing it? https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb

Comment: he has not mention anywhere that application need not to run once.AFAIK this is basic concept of android.Your receiver will work once it start