# BroadcastReceiver for Network State Changed not called when app isn't openen after installing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

For my Android app I made a BroadcastReceiver which is triggered on `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`, defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. This works fine, except when you don't open the app after installation. In that case it looks like the BroadcastReceiver isn't registered yet. The same thing is happening for the BroadcastReceiver which is triggered on `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Is it possible that the registering of the BroadcastReceivers according the Manifest only happens when the app is opened after installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the same problem as [Android broadcast receiver not getting called immediately after install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092640/android-broadcast-receiver-not-getting-called-immediately-after-install?rq=1)

The best [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9092855/1358366) tells it isn't possible, and in the reply the asker refers to [this app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.lookout.labs.planb). But this app only works on Android 2.0 - 2.3. So this probably means that in newer Android version the `BroadcastReceivers` only register when app is opened once. If someone does have a workaround, I'd be happy to know. :)